# How do you prevent BIOS from attempting to boot from other ssds?

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, bios

[image: Partitions]

I have the drives and partitions on my PC as shown above. I want C: to boot (the third partition in Disk 3). However, for some reason the bios tries to first load DISK 0-2 which obviously fail before finally loading Windows 10 from Disk 3. How do I make the bios stop trying to load the other hard drives which clearly don't have any operating systems installed. The motherboard is Z370 AORUS GAMING WIFI (rev. 1.0). I also completely disabled all other drives from the boot order configuration in bios settings, but it still tries to load them. Are my partitions set up in some way that triggers the bios to want to load them? I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm looking for a solution because it annoys me that it slows down the startup speed so much.

Comment: Can you include the exact messages you're seeing when the OS is trying to "boot from disks 0–2"? So far what you describe (BIOS boot) doesn't quite match what the screenshot is showing (EFI boot).

Comment: What is on `G:`?

Comment: Ok, it's not a BIOS boot. I'm using UEFI. The reason why I think that those disks (or at least some of them) are attempted to be booted from is because I have a blinking underscore appear for about 5-10 seconds, several times, before Windows 10 is finally loaded. It looks something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T1Pa.jpg (not my image). And the screen flashes about 2-3 times, leading to believe it's attempting to load 2-3 different partitions. This never occurred with my previous setup. It would just immediately load to Windows 10.

Comment: Disk 1 contains an old corrupt windows installation. I can delete `G:`. It doesn't really serve a purpose.

Comment: Could you show `bcdedit /enum firmware`?

Comment: Sure, https://pastebin.com/raw/eaKkyVWk

Comment: @notorious - Your system is not attempting to boot any other disk except `608ab659-125c-11ea-b7e9-9e89cf9cf5cd` and `fwbootmgr` the slowness comes from the fact `fwbootmgr` isn't first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows disk has an UEFI-style partition layout. In the UEFI boot process, the firmware usually doesn't boot a 'disk' – it boots a specific OS *by name*. So placing disk 3 before disks 0–2 is going to be meaningless, because **Windows isn't booting from "disk 3" in the first place.**

As you can see in `bcdedit /enum firmware`, in addition to the disk entries meant for "legacy boot", there is also an entry that directly points to the Windows bootloader. It's *this* entry that needs to be placed topmost in the boot order.

(Some firmwares expose this in their setup screens as a multi-level thing, where you might need to move "UEFI" above "Legacy", or something like that.)

You should be able to do this from within Windows using the special {fwbootmgr} object, which directly propagates changes to EFI firmware settings:

```
bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder {bootmgr}
```

(This sets Windows Boot Manager as the *only* item in the boot order. Your firmware will likely re-add the legacy disk entries at the end, that can be safely ignored.)

Comment: I ran the command, but it reverts back to the old displayorder when I restart the computer. Now I have: https://pastebin.com/raw/5pp7jfHA Also, it does it 5 times now, instead of 3

Comment: In that case, try explicitly listing *all* possible entries in the order you want (space-separated), or figure out how to do it from the UEFI setup screen (it _has_ to be in there somewhere).

Comment: I tried `Bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder {bootmgr} /addfirst` and it still reverts to the old ordering

Comment: I fixed it with `Bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder {default}`. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.